# How can i find user id and country with Session

Tags: php, mysql, session

These are my userpanel codes.

On this page, I show username and pass with session code. How can I show this user country on this page?

Thanks
I have "uyeler" table. Rows are fname,lname,mail,password,country

Panel.php

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["kullanici"]) && isset($_SESSION["sifre"])){
    /*If there are sessions for username and password */
    echo "Hoşgeldiniz, ".$_SESSION["kullanici"] .$_SESSION["sifre"];
    /*We wrote welcome with username */

?>

<br />
<a href="yonetim.php?cikis=1" title="Çıkış Yap">Çıkış</a>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["cikis"])){
    if($_GET["cikis"]==1){
        $_SESSION=array();
        echo "Tüm işlemleriniz silindi.Çıkış Yaptınız.Yönlendiriliyorsunuz";
        echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=giris.php">';
    }

}}else{
    /*Oluşturulmamışsa giriş kısmına yönlendireceğiz.*/
    echo "Çok yanlış geldin ...<br /> Yönlendiriliyorsun...";
    echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=giris.php">';
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';


foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM uyeler') as $row) {
    echo $row['fname'] . "\t";
    echo $row['lname'] . "\t";
    echo $row['mail'] . "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: *"I show username and **pass** with session code."* - **Not** a good idea.

Comment: yes i konw but for now i am trying to learning php

Comment: you have no SQL in your question, that makes it harder for us to help.

Comment: you need to add a `WHERE` clause related to the user, and add `$row['country']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT country FROM uyeler WHERE mail ='{$_SESSION['kullanici']}'") as $row) { echo $row['country']; }
```

It works thank you :)